# How to register a user input to a list C#

Tags: c#

Hi im trying to get a user to make a list of words. Next step is for the user to type one of the words again and then the program will check for anagrams in the list. I have found a way to solve it but ONLY when checking my own list.
I would like to know how to do what I need. no need for exact code answear just some help on the way. Still New at C# and coding. Dont mind the swedish comments.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Skriv lite olika ord:");
        string[] words = Console.ReadLine().Split(null);
        Console.WriteLine("Tackar! Välj ett av orden för att kolla ifall det finns Anagram ordet:");
        string[] word = Console.ReadLine().Split(null);

        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        bool match = false;


        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            words[i] = words[i].Trim();

        //Loopar igenom alla ord i arrayen, börjar med första ordet.
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            result.Add(words[i]);
            //Loopar igenom arrays med nästkommande ord.
            for (int c = 2; c < words.Length; c++)
            {
               //Gämför bara ifall orden har lika många bokstäver och struntar i "tomma" ord
                if(words[i].Length == words[c].Length && words[i] !="")
                {
                    //Konverterar orden till CharArray
                    char[] a = words[i].ToUpper().ToCharArray();
                    char[] b = words[c].ToUpper().ToCharArray();
                    //Soreterar orden i bokstavsordning
                    Array.Sort(a);
                    Array.Sort(b);

                    match = false;
                    //sätter en counter för att kunna räkna
                    int counter = 0;
                    //Loppar igen alla bokstäver i orden man jämför
                    // Om den hittar någon bokstav som inte stämmer överens så returners False.
                    // Om alla bokstäver mathar så return true.
                    foreach(char x in a)
                    {
                        if (x == b[counter])
                            match = true;
                        else
                        {
                            match = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }
                    // om alla bokstäver "matchar" så läggs de till i listan
                    // har words[c] = ""; ifall den hittar tomma strings
                    if(match)
                    {
                        result.Add(words[c]);
                        words[c] = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            // om listan bara blir 1 ord så hittas ingen match
            if (result.Count() > 1 && result[0] != "")
            {
                Console.Write("Anagrams: ");
                foreach (string s in result)
                    Console.Write(s + " ");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            //återställer listan
            result.Clear();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: If you want the user to enter a word you can just call Console.ReadLine. I suggest you check for empty string to exit from the program. By the way use words.Length rather than words.Count()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is actually quite simple.
You just have to check every word which fits the amount of letters, if they share the same letters.

E.g. `word` has 4 letters. If a user types in `what` which has 5 letters they can't possible match. But if he types in `darn` which is also 4 u just have to check if all letters match.

One should keep an eye on Case-Sensitivity, which I left out to make the answer more simple.
As well there are numerous ways to improve this code which i left out. All in the name of simplicity :)

```
    static void Main(string[] param)
    {
        //The list of Words which are anagrams
        List<string> solutions = new List<string>();

        //get the user input
        string userInput = "User writes arm ram kola like hi"; //Replace with Console.ReadLine().ToLower(); and don't forget to prompt the userwith input

        //split it into the diffrent words
        string[] words = userInput.Split(' ');

        //get the users "match want"
        string userMatchWant = "mar"; //Replace with Console.ReadLine().ToLower(); and don't forget to prompt the userwith input

        //Find words wich are as long as mar
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            //if they arn't the same length it can't be an anagramm
            if (word.Length != userMatchWant.Length)
                continue;

            //To Determin if all characters of the words are the same
            bool hasOnlyTheSameLetters = false;

            //now check if all characters contains
            foreach (char c in word)
            {
                //If The lette is in the word assume it contains only of the letters that we are looking for, because
                if (userMatchWant.Contains(c.ToString()))
                    hasOnlyTheSameLetters = true;
                //else we know it has a different word so we can breack and check the other input words.
                else
                {
                    hasOnlyTheSameLetters = false;
                    break;
                }                        
            }

            //if there is a diffrence in letters contine
            if (hasOnlyTheSameLetters == false)
                continue;
            //else add the word to the solution
            else
                solutions.Add(word);
        }

        //Print the solutions
        if(solutions.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.Write("Anagrams: ");
            foreach (string s in solutions)
                Console.Write( s  + " ");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

For all you LINQ fanatics out there, this is the shortest way I could come up with, to replace the foreach(string word in words) - Loop:
`var totalMatches = words.Where(p => p.Length == userMatchWant.Length).Where(p => p.All(c => userMatchWant.Contains(c.ToString())));`

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not perfectly clear, but I suspect you are looking for `Console.ReadLine()` and `string.Split()`, combined as:

```
string[] words = Console.ReadLine().Split(null);
```

which will return all substrings separated by whitespace.

There are other forms of `string.Split` you should explore where you can specify what characters to split by and to remove blank entries from the result

Comment: There is no overload of [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes zero arguments

Comment: Thanks! That solves part of my problem. One still remains. The Anagram check should not appear right after the list. I want the user to Write one of the words they just wrote in the list and then the program should check if that last word we wrote have an Anagram in the list we just wrote. Following? :)  
     
now I get like this: Write a list of words: älg lag gäl hej lol Thanks! Type one of the words to check for anagram: Anagrams: älg gäl So all jsut pops up instead of just one word we use to compare

Answer (score 1):

This is how you read the user input:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Write a list of Words");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    List<string> words = input.Split(' ').ToList();
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    bool match = false;
```

this should lead to:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That solves part of my problem. One still remains. The Anagram check should not appear right after the list. I want the user to Write one of the words they just wrote in the list and then the program should check if that last word we wrote have an Anagram in the list we just wrote. Following? :)

Comment: now I get like this: Write a list of words:
älg lag gäl hej lol
Thanks! Type one of the words to check for anagram:
Anagrams: älg gäl

So all jsut pops up instead of just one word we use to compare

Answer (score 0):

I suggest having a *dictionary* (or *lookup*) instead of *list* and group all anagrams with the same key. Key is sorted letters within the word (so we have `"amr"` after sorting 'r', 'a', 'm' in the '"ram"' and value is the set of initial words)

```
  amr: {mar, arm, ram}
  egl: {Elg, gel}
```

The imlementation

```
  private static string MakeKey(string value) {
    return string.Concat(value
      .Select(c => char.ToUpper(c)) // let's be case insensitive
      .OrderBy(c => c));
  }

  private static void AddWord(Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> words, string word) {
    string key = MakeKey(word);

    HashSet<string> anagrams; 

    if (words.TryGetValue(key, out anagrams))
      anagrams.Add(word);
    else 
      words.Add(key, new HashSet<string>() {word});            
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
    Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> words = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>(); 

    // Let user input all the words separating them either by spaces or by commas etc. 
    var initialWords = Console
      .ReadLine()
      .Split(new char[] { ' ', ',', ';', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 

    foreach (var word in initialWords) 
      AddWord(words, word);
```

Dictionaries are much more efficient `O(N)` v. `O(N**2)` in case of large word arrays (what if you want to analyze the entire Swedish vocabulary?). 
In order to obtain anagrams we should filter out the pairs from dictionary s.t. contain at least 2 words in `Value`:

```
  var report = words
    .Where(pair => pair.Value.Count > 1) // at least 2 words share the same key
    .Select(pair => string.Join(", ", pair
      .Value
      .OrderBy(item => item))) // let us be nice and ordering anagrams
    .OrderBy(item => item);    // let us be nice and ordering anagrams

   Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, report));
```

The outcome is

```
  arm, ram
  Elg, gel
  era, rea
  för, frö
```

Answer (score 0):

Thankful for the answers so far! I think my explanation of the problem was a little to weak. The user input is now fixed BUT the last problem still remains.
After the user wrote their input they get another Question "Type one of the words in the list to look for anagrams?" But my problem is that my program runs all my anagrams instead of just the word we picked in the second question. :/